# TCP Health Monitor

Tags: apigee

I have a load balancer group with few target servers and they are SSL enabled.
Now I want to do the TCP monitoring on the target servers port (443)

Does TCP monitor work with the backends which are on https ?

Answer (score 0):

TCP Monitor, according to me, does a socket connect on the given Host and Port. What this means is, if there is an open port on the target server, then server is considered alive and kicking.

Since this is only a socket connect; protocol HTTP,HTTPS does not matter as long as there is port open and has a listener on the port.

Comment: Agree . but what I found was , no TCP connections being made for my configured interval to the backend if the target server is https and I can see tcp packets if the target server is http.